# TeeChart - Pie or Donut labelling the inside pie of a donut

Tags: c#, .net, teechart, donut-chart

I am using Steema.TeeChart for .Net (coding in C#)
Does someone know how to lable inside of a pie of a donut chart.
It should look like:
http://www.steema.com/uploads/gallery/DonutNET.png
Hope for help.
Barbara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to get a similar image using code such as this:

```
private void InitializeChart()
{
  Donut series = new Donut(tChart1.Chart);
  series.FillSampleValues();
  series.Marks.Visible = true;
  series.Marks.Transparent = true;
  series.Marks.Arrow.Visible = false;
  series.Marks.ArrowLength = -10;
}
```

Please let me know if that isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. This was the solution of my problem :-)